# List folderName and file contents in listview

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to list the subfolders and its files in a asp.net listview without using a Sql table?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to list them recursively or only a single level of the folder's contents?

Comment: Yes there is.  You will need to ask a specific programming question to get help here though.

Comment: There is going to be folders like: 1234, 5832, 123123. In these folders there are files fd3_xxx_stmt, fd3_xxx_war,fd3_xxx_tax. My listview has three columns statements, warrant, and tax. If folder 1234 has these files then my listview should have under the statements column : 1234\fd3_xxx_stmt, warrant column: 1234\fd3_xxx_war

Comment: Yes, you can do this; it won't be a problem.  But you need to research the System.IO namespace, specificially the Directory static object, DirectoryInfo class, and others.  This is too broad of a question for anybody to help.

Comment: Currently I can access the files in the directory but am not sure how to place them under a specific column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have a **listview** named `ListView1`
You can do it with something like the following to list filenames.:

```
static void ListFiles(string sDir)
   {
       try
       {
           foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
           {
               foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
               {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
                    item.Tag =  f; //could get folder name: DirectoryInfo(d).Name


                    ListView1.Items.Add(item);
               }
               ListFiles(d);
           }
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {
           // handle exceptions here!
       }
   }
```